# How to do: in one class ::after content to display and in another class ::after content not display?

Tags: jquery

It is necessary to add a class to `.exposed-filter-icon` using toogleClass and display `::after` `content` in one class and not display `::after` `content` in another class (set unset). This is necessary so that when nothing is selected in the form, the icon is not displayed where the number of selected form elements.

scss:

```
.exposed-filter-icon {
   // code
  &::after {
    content: attr(data-after);
     // code
  }
}
```

Jquery:

```
const quantityCheckedElements = $(".tag-label").length;
if (quantityCheckedElements == 0) {

}
if (quantityCheckedElements >= 1) {
    $(".exposed-filter-icon").attr(
    "data-after",
    quantityCheckedElements
  );
}
```

What needs to be added in jquery code?

Comment: `.exposed-filter-icon {`-> `.exposed-filter-icon[data-after] {` then remove the attr when you don't want it shown.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't super clear what you are asking, but if I understand you correctly

> "...when nothing is selected in the form, the icon is not displayed"

all you need to do is use the `removeAttr` method. You can also rationalise and simplify your conditional logic. e.g.

```
const quantityCheckedElements = $(".tag-label").length;

// in Javascript positive integers equate to "true", and "0" equates to "false"
if (quantityCheckedElements) {
  $(".exposed-filter-icon").attr(
    "data-after",
    quantityCheckedElements
  );
} else {
  $(".exposed-filter-icon").removeAttr("data-after");
}
```

see: https://api.jquery.com/removeattr/